# Implementing an LSTM cell with Tensorflow without using tf.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

My task is to implement a basic LSTM Network for letter recognition from motion sensor data from an android phone without using any modules from tf.contrib. The input data has the shape (?, 150, 3) --> ?: # of letters, 150: # of values, 3: x,y,z coordinates.

The plan is to build a LSTM Cell and use the Adam Optimizer for adjusting the weights. The Problem is, the fct. LSTM is executed before I feed the data in sess.run(). How can I prevent the graph from executing? Do I have to put all the code in a class or is there another way?

**Code**

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_features * fixed_length_of_feed_array])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5])

x_r = tf.reshape(x, [-1, fixed_length_of_feed_array, 3])

states = [tf.random_normal([hidden, hidden]), tf.random_normal([hidden, hidden])]


def LSTM_Cell(hidden, inputs, states):

    x_i = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_r, wx[:, :hidden]), bx[:, :hidden])
    x_f = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_r, wx[:, hidden:hidden * 2]), bx[:, hidden:hidden * 2])
    x_c = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_r, wx[:, hidden * 2:hidden * 3]), bx[:, hidden * 2:hidden * 3])
    x_o = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_r, wx[:, hidden * 3:]), bx[:, hidden * 3:])

    hi = tf.sigmoid(tf.concat([tf.matmul(states[0], wh[:, :hidden]), x_i], 1))
    hf = tf.sigmoid(tf.concat([tf.matmul(states[0], wh[:, hidden:hidden * 2]), x_f], 1))
    ho = tf.sigmoid(tf.concat([tf.matmul(states[0], wh[:, hidden * 2:hidden * 3]), x_o], 1))
    hc = tf.tanh(tf.concat([tf.matmul(states[0], wh[:, hidden * 3:]), x_c], 1))

    c = tf.multiply(hf, states[1]) + tf.multiply(hi, hc)
    h = tf.multiply(ho, tf.tanh(c))

    return h, c


def LSTM(hidden, inputs, states):

    arr_inputs = inputs.split()

    return LSTM_Cell(hidden, arr_inputs, states)


# pred
h, c = LSTM(hidden, x_r, states)
states[0], states[1] = h, c
y = tf.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(h, wy), by))
```

Answer (score 0):

The LSTM is not executed before you feed data with session.run. Instead, your python code executes and builds a graph, which only gets evaluated later.